# Equivalent of the Scala IDE worksheet in other languages?

Tags: java, python, ruby, ide

> A worksheet is a Scala file that is evaluated on save, and the result of each expression is shown in a column to the right of your program. Worksheets are like a REPL session on steroids, and enjoy 1st class editor support: completion, hyperlinking, interactive errors-as-you-type, auto-format, etc. (source https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-worksheet/wiki/Getting-Started)

Is there anything similar in any other language? I mean, I know about REPL in other dynamic languages, but what the worksheet does s much more.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not really a language feature, more an IDE feature.

It looks like a pretty straightforward clone of the `Transcript` window which has been a standard part of Smalltalk IDEs since at the least the 1980s.

*One* of those Smalltalk IDEs is IBM VisualAge for Smalltalk (where it was called *Scrapbook*), which later became IBM VisualAge for Java, which became IBM VisualAge for Java Micro Edition, which became Eclipse, and in fact [the Eclipse Java Development Tools *still* have that feature today](http://Help.Eclipse.Org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/cscrapbook.htm).

Lisp and Forth IDEs also usually have something similar, often called a *listener*.

[LINQPad](http://LINQPad.Net/) is a product which provides a similar experience for C#, VisualBasic.NET and F#.

[Pry](http://PryREPL.Org/) is still in its infancy, but its goal is to morph into a full interactive IDE for Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

[IPython](http://ipython.org/) does something very similar for Python with its web-based worksheets feature.

Answer (score -2):

F# has this feature as well. You can write F# statements in an F# script and then evaluate in the console. You can also reference F# source files or compiled binaries.

Comment: "A worksheet is a Scala file that is evaluated on save, and the result of each expression is shown in a column to the right of your program."